# python scrapying font awesome icons(fa-fa icons) in the page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to extract data in a website that have some font awesome icons like this one `<i class="fa fa-check-square green-icon font-095"></i>`

mostly there're two types of icons meaning **"correct"** or **"wrong"**, I wanna to extract this as 1 and 0(if correct 1 else 0)

are there any suggestions of how I can extract this type of data?

Comment: The difference between the  "correct" and  "wrong" icons is the class `green-icon` or `red-icon`?

Comment: Actually, that does not relate to the question. that defines after I extract the icons how I will use them.
I just wanna know if I can extract the font awesome icons

Answer (score 2):

In terms of extracting this data you can use the BeautifulSoup and Requests libraries. It would look something like this...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("www.website-you-want.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
rows = soup.find_all('i')
```

This should get you every occurrence of the i tag on the page. If you wanted to be more specific you could do something along the lines of...

```
rows = soup.find_all('i', {'class', 'green-icon'})
```

This should get you every occurrence of the i tag with the green-icon class.

NOTE: If the website is dynamically loading content, you will have to use selenium with beautiful soup. Let me know if that's the case and I can try to help with that.

Comment: Thank you, by using Scrapy I did the same as long as my website is dynamically and URLs are changeable.